# Dashboard widget to display number of queryitems across multiple iterations in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, workitem

I would like to display a graph on the Azure Devops dashboard, which for each specific iteration paths (may last 3 iterations) shows how many work items with a specific tag there were.

Is that possible with existing widgets in Azure Devops? Or is there any other simple way of doing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First query based on the following fields, and then save the query as **Shared Queries**.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Then add **chart for Work Items widget** in dashboard -> Import shared query in Configuration -> Get the graph

[image]
[image]

**Update**:

1. Add Iteration Path column in Column options

[image]

2. In the chart, `Group by` select **Iteration Path**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I need a chart which displays across multiple iterations, and this the above cannot do.

Comment: @Jihad Haddad Please view my updated image, add multiple `Iteration path` fileds, use `or` to associate these iterations.

Comment: Or you can specify multiple iterations in the value, separated by commas. Use `In` operator.

Comment: Thanks. That will give me total for all iterations. I want a total for each iteration and I believe the above cannot do that. I know my question might need modification to reflect my wishes, but I was afraid to overcomplicate the question.

Comment: @Jihad Haddad This is achievable, we just need to add the iteration path column and then select Group by `Iteration Path` in the chart.Please view my update in the answer.